# Not able to remove all D3 SVG elements

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to remove all children of my SVG element and I'm having issues removing `lines`.  When I have `text` and `circles` in my SVG element, I can easily wipe them with the command `d3.select("#id_svg-graph").selectAll("*").remove()`.  However, I recently added lines to my SVG element and they persist even after this command.  Is there any reason for this?

This is the SVG before the command:

```
<svg id="id_svg-graph" style="height:100%;width:100%;" width="1522" height="407">
    <line style="stroke: black;" x1="823" y1="183" x2="660" y2="156">
    <circle style="fill: chartreuse; stroke: gold;" r="20" cx="660" cy="156">
    <circle style="fill: chartreuse; stroke: black;" r="20" cx="823" cy="183">
    <text style="-moz-user-select: none;" text-anchor="middle" x="660" y="156">0</text>
    <text style="-moz-user-select: none;" text-anchor="middle" x="823" y="183">1</text>
</svg>
```

And after the command:

```
<svg id="id_svg-graph" style="height:100%;width:100%;" width="1522" height="407">
    <line style="stroke: black;" x1="823" y1="183" x2="660" y2="156">
</svg>
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure why the line's and circle's don't have an end bracket, but they've been working fine so far.  I use D3 to generate the elements, so I never actually write the code that is shown above.

I've also tried changing the name to not have a '-', but it didn't change the problem any... and it seemed to work just fine with the '-' in, so I kept it.

The problem is that only the line elements aren't disappearing.  Even after specifying the lines explicitly with `d3.select("#id_svg-graph").selectAll("line").remove()`, they still persist.

I'm using Firefox 45.2.0 if that might help diagnose what's happening here.

Comment: First of all, your SVG is not valid XML as the `<line>` element as well as both `<circle>` elements are not closed, i.e. they are missing a `/>`. That may or may not contribute to the issue. Nonetheless, your code as it is works for me in Chrome 51, FF 47 and IE 11 having tried both D3 v3 ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1zgqmts/)) and v4 ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cntdnasL/)).

Answer (score 3):

The id for the svg root is not valid. Try removing the dash
e.g.:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <svg id="id_svgGraph" style="height:100%;width:100%;" width="1522" height="407">
<line style="stroke: black;" x1="823" y1="183" x2="660" y2="156">
<circle style="fill: chartreuse; stroke: gold;" r="20" cx="660" cy="156">
<circle style="fill: chartreuse; stroke: black;" r="20" cx="823" cy="183">
<text style="-moz-user-select: none;" text-anchor="middle" x="660" y="156">0</text>
<text style="-moz-user-select: none;" text-anchor="middle" x="823" y="183">1</text>
</svg>
<script>
d3.select("#id_svgGraph").selectAll("*").remove()
console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(id_svgGraph))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The id is valid it's just difficult to use as you need to CSS escape the minus sign in the selector as \- if you really want to keep it.